# git advanced alias parameter issues

Tags: git, git-alias

Suppose I have this in my .gitconfig alias:

```
testing =!"\
echo \"hi\" \
"
```

if I run `git testing 1 4` it will echo the parameters back to me:

```
hi 1 4
```

Also if I use sh to try to get all the parameters it doesn't show the first:

```
testing =!sh -c 'echo "$@"'
```

if I run `git testing 1 4` it will only show `4`.

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

If your `sh` is `bash`, then the [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) has some info:

> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Before you get a chance to access `$@`, Bash interprets the `-c` and will pass the subsequent arguments through as parameters to the sub shell. This means `$0` will be the next value passed, which is 4 (essentially `$@` and `$0` are the same at this point because there is only one value).

If you run the `sh` with `-v` you will see slightly more about what is happening:

```
$ git testing 1 4
echo $@
4
```

So the `echo $@` gets only 4 in its arguments. The `-c` will create a sub shell, and pass `$@` though. Remember this contains only 4 now. This is where you are losing the 1.

Comment: Nice, I like the precise explanation of why the parameter is missing. I didn't address that in my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC, thanks mate. Always hard to get an answer in when you're on the case :)

Comment: Why does `$@` only contain 4, though, at *any* point? At the point when Bash interprets `-c`, why is `$@` just `4` instead of `1 4`?

Comment: @acanby Thanks but I'm confused. In my first example why are the parameters echoed back to me? And in my second example as @Kyle said why is it just 4 instead of 1 4. Aren't `1` and `4` both subsequent arguments to testing?

Comment: Maybe you meant that `$@` and `$1` are the same, since `$@` should never include the 0 argument?

Comment: @acanby Hi I'd like to mark this as correct but can you please clear up the confusion first.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested:

```
testing = !sh -c 'echo "$@"' {};
```

This does display *all* the parameters.

This is similar to "[find: missing argument to `-exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962015/6309)"

> A `-exec` command must be terminated with a `;` (so you usually need to type `\;` or `';'` to avoid interpretation by the shell)

This would work too:

```
[alias]
    testing = "!f() { echo \"$@\"; }; f"
```

Comment: the semi-colon in the first example doesn't seem to make a difference, it's the braces that do though. Why is that? The second example also works.

Comment: @newguy `{}` forces the execution of the `sh -c` command in the context of the current shell instead of creating a subshell (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048024/6309)