# What are "double sh" calls?

Tags: bash

Can you explain what are (as I call it) "double sh calls", how they work and the advantages of such constructs ?

EDIT1 : Maybe an example can help you understand what I'm talking about.

```
$ set -- --no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
$ sh -c 'echo $*'
$
$ sh -c 'echo $*' sh "$*"
--no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
```

I couln't find any example of this in the man :

```
$ man bash | col -b | egrep "sh -c [\"']"
$
```

N.B.: If the title of my question is ambiguous, please help me change it because I don't know how to call such shell calls.

Comment: What is your question.? Are you just looking for understanding what `sh -c` is and how it works. If so your answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/23951346/5291015

Comment: @Inian Nope. Please take a little more time and see my EDIT1 and the example below it so as to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Inian Please reconsider your down-vote and see my EDIT2 and the example below it that I've just updated, hope this helps make myself understood.

Comment: I did NOT downvote your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man bash` describes `-c` and its arguments:

> If  the  `-c`  option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument *command_string*.  If there are  arguments  after  the  *command_string*, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

In this case, the *command_string* is `echo $*`, and the positional arguments are set in this way:

```
$0 = sh
$1 = "$*" = '--no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/'
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT2 and the example below it that I've just updated, hope this helps make myself understood

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's the second `sh` call doing after the subshell script : `sh -c 'script'` ?

Comment: It's not a call, it's a value assigned to `$0`.

Comment: In MY example, what is the second `sh` doing after the subshell script : sh -c 'script' ?

Comment: If you mean this: `sh -c 'echo $*' sh "$*"`, then the second `sh` is the value `$0` gets set to as I've already explained.

Comment: I am finally starting to understand, at last :) So the second `sh` and what follows it are just the $0, $1, ... of the first `sh -c` subscript parameters, right ?

Comment: @SebMa Exactly.