# How set an exit code when exiting bash?

Tags: bash, pipestatus

I want to run a command from a sub-bash and I need the return code from it; actually it's running  a pipeline and I need the PIPESTATUS array, or at least one component.

This was my best guess and it does not work. I just get a 0. Since bash did not error it makes sense, it's just not what I need.  Help?

```
bash -c "echo 123 | grep abc | sort; exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with single quotes:

```
bash -c 'echo 123 | grep abc | sort; exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]}'; echo $?
```

**Sample runs:**

```
bash -c 'echo 123 | grep abc | sort; exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]}'; echo $?
1

bash -c 'echo 123 | grep abc | sort; echo status is ${PIPESTATUS[@]}'; echo $?
status is 0 1 0
0
```

There is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951346/is-there-a-subshell-created-when-i-run-sh-c-command-a-new-shell-or-none-of/24041668#24041668) on this.